# Showing AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'nrows' in xlrd python?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlrd

I am reading the excel file in python using xlrd module. The sample code is below

```
import xlrd
import sys
import glob

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('nvm_sw_cfg_parm_master_v85.xlsx')
sheet_names = workbook.sheet_names()
print('Sheet Names', sheet_names)
for sheet in sheet_names:
    print sheet
    print sheet.nrows
```

This is the sample code which i trying. In this code i can able to read the sheets name but when i read the total no of rows in sheets it shows error like

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'nrows'
```

I have gone through the library file documentation there is a class name call **sheet** inside that **nrows** is defined, how could i call this from the code, kindly can someone help me to solve this error or any other module for reading the excel file.

Answer (score 1):

An `xlrd` `sheet` does have a `nrows` attribute. But your code is setting the variable `sheet` to a string value. This line:

```
sheet_names = workbook.sheet_names()
```

returns a list of *names* not *sheets*. If you want more information about the sheets than their names, your code needs to retrieve the sheets, not just their names:

```
sheets = workbook.sheets()
for sheet in sheets:
    ...
```

Then the variable `sheet` will actually contain a sheet, and not just a string.